# How to capture variable parameters with Mockito?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

There is a method which has variable parameters:

```
class A {
    public void setNames(String... names) {}
}
```

Now I want to mock it with `mockito`, and capture the names passed to it. But I can't find a way to capture any number of names passed, I can only get them like this:

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> captor1 = ArgumentCaptor.fromClass(String.class);
ArgumentCaptor<String> captor2 = ArgumentCaptor.fromClass(String.class);

A mock = Mockito.mock(A.class);
mock.setNames("Jeff", "Mike");
Mockito.verity(mock).setNames(captor1.capture(), captor2.capture());
String name1 = captor1.getValue(); // Jeff
String name2 = captor2.getValue(); // Mike
```

If I pass three names, it won't work, and I have to define a `captor3` to capture the 3rd name.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 57):

Mockito 1.10.5 has introduced this feature.

For the code sample in the question, here is one way to capture the varargs:

```
    ArgumentCaptor<String> varArgs = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
    A mock = Mockito.mock(A.class);
    mock.setNames("Jeff", "Mike", "John");
    Mockito.verify(mock).setNames(varArgs.capture());

    //Results may be validated thus:
    List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("Jeff", "Mike", "John");
    assertEquals(expected, varArgs.getAllValues());
```

Please see the [ArgumentCaptor javadoc](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/1.10.5/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) for details.

Comment: Do you happen to know whether this works with subclasses? E.g. String.format(String fromat, Object ... args) and invokation with instances of different types (yeah, I know String is final, it's just an example)?

Comment: @nachteil Yes, `ArgumentCaptor<T>` can capture all subclass instances of `T`. e.g., use `ArgumentCaptor<Object>` to capture all types of objects.  Please note, a static method like String.format() cannot be mocked or spied upon with Mockito.  Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito) answer for details.

Comment: Is it possible to capture instance variable or local variable in junit ?

Answer (score 3):

As of today (7 Nov 2013) it appears to be addressed, but unreleased, with a bit of additional work needed. See the [groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mockito/TkM_dK09S3M) and [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=372) for details.